# Table name list from My SQL database

Tags: php, mysql

Can anybody help me how to show a table names list from a database? 
I tried (select * from tab) query.But its not working.Please help me...I need query using My SQL...

Comment: Have you not googled it? because its too localize question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or the more standards based approach -

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name'
```

[INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tables-table.html)

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer that you decide to use. Just click on the tick to the left of your preferred answer.

Answer (score 3):

first use that database `use mydatabase;`
then  list tables using `show tables;`

Answer (score 0):

Use this-

```
show tables;
```

But if you are using different database previously, then use-

```
use database_name;
```

and then use  `show tables;`